# how to dynamically increase the height of the devexpress grid as no of rows increases

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I am implementing a Devexpress grid.i want to increase the height of the grid as no of rows increase.as i am not setting pagesize.

Please suggest you thoughts.

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 0):

You should use the GridView.RowCountChanged event 
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_RowCountChangedtopic

Comment: Also check the DevExpress grid article "How to change the Grid's height according to the total height of its rows" for a code example https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1811